# cursor.moveToNext() not working in onLoadFinished after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-loadermanager

I'm using custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` to show the list items. I'm using `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` to fetch the data from the database and in `onLoadFinished()` I use custom method to extract the data from the cursor and store it in the custom ArrayList one by one using `while(cursor.moveToNext())`. The list is loaded successfully. But upon screen rotation the list goes off.

When I debugged the code I got to know that the `onLoadFinished()` is called on screen rotation but the while loop is not working even if the cursor is not null and cursor count is greater than 0.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    loadAndroidFlavours(cursor);

    mCursor = cursor;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private void loadAndroidFlavours(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int columnIndexID = cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidFlavourEntry._ID);
            int columnIndexFlavour = cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidFlavourEntry.COLUMN_FLAVOUR);
            int columnIndexVersion = cursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidFlavourEntry.COLUMN_VERSION);

            int ID = cursor.getInt(columnIndexID);
            String flavour = cursor.getString(columnIndexFlavour);
            String version = cursor.getString(columnIndexVersion);

            mFavoritesList.add(new AndroidFlavour(ID, flavour, version));
        }
        loadAndroidFlavours();
    } else {
        hideList();
    }
}
```

I'm stuck. Please help with explanation. Regards!

Comment: Can you share a part of your code ?

Comment: Please share your code....

Comment: Because when you rotate the screen you lose all your state and you have to query again. A better alternative is that you store the list elements in your save bundle and reload from there.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: Ok. But when I simply use CursorAdapter to load the data then even upon screen rotation the data is still shown in the list without using onSaveInstanceState()